# Инициализация модели Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jsp

При генерации jsp страницы необходимо модель контроллера проинициализировать текстовым значением, содержащим html-разметку. Если в этой строке попадаются например символы кавычек, все ломается. Можно ли как-то например экранировать текстовое значение или есть другие способы инициализации модели?

```
<div ng-init="model.data='${company.description}'"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Вы можете попробовать следующее. Инициализировать вашу переменную, используя функцию `ng-init` и получить внутренний **html** с помощью `document.querySelector`.

Хотя это и будет плохая практика - смешивание **angular**  и работа с **DOM** непосредственно с контроллера.

Пример на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/qoanok28/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope, $sce) {
    // Get html value from server side
    $scope.getHtmlValue = function() {
        $scope.bind = angular.element(document.querySelector('#divHTML')).html();
      }
      // need to show html
    $scope.getHtmlByBind = function() {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.bind);
    }
    //just show in console
    $scope.showBind = function() {
      console.log($scope.bind);
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <form name="testForm">
      <div ng-init="getHtmlValue()" id="divHTML">
       <!--  It's your server generation value, like ${company.description}  -->
        lorem <b>ipsum</b>
        <br> fgdf
        <!--   -->
      </div>
      <button ng-click="showBind()">
        show in console
      </button>
      <h2>
    Generation html from ng-model
    </h2>
    <textarea ng-model="bind" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
      <div ng-bind-html="getHtmlByBind()">
      </div>
      <h2>
    Sanitize html
    </h2>
      <div ng-bind="bind">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Хотя это и считается плохой практикой, тем не менее - Вы можете так сделать. 
Подробнее про [$sanitize](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize/service/$sanitize).

По хорошему, Вам необходимо сделать запрос к Вашему серверу (возможно, сервлету) через [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).
И уже там получить Ваше значение и использовать его на стороне клиента.

### UPDATED

Найдено более эелегантное решение - использование **директивы (directive)**. В это случае не надо ставить `id` элемента.

Пример на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/xr0jemaq/).

```js
angular.module('ExampleApp', [])
  .controller('ExampleController', function($scope, $sce) {
    // need to show html
    $scope.getHtmlByBind = function() {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml($scope.bind);
    }
    $scope.showBind = function() {
      console.log($scope.bind);
    }
  })
  .directive('valueFromServer', function() {
    return {
      restrict: "AE",
      scope: {
        value: "=",
      },
      link: function(scope, elem) {
        scope.value = elem.html();
      }
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<div ng-app="ExampleApp">
  <div ng-controller="ExampleController">
    <form name="testForm">

      <value-from-server value="bind">
        <!--  It's your server generation value  -->
        gf<b>112312</b>gdfgdf
        <br>vxcv
      </value-from-server>
      <br>
      <button ng-click="showBind()">
        show in console
      </button>
      <h2>
    Generation html from ng-model
    </h2>
      <textarea ng-model="bind" cols="40" rows="5"></textarea>
      <div ng-bind-html="getHtmlByBind()">
      </div>
      <h2>
    Sanitize html
    </h2>
      <div ng-bind="bind">
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Повторюсь - это плохое решение.